# Saying "You'll feel me on this"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, conversation, register

So, recently, I saw someone commenting, "You'll feel me on this" on a certain post. Since I'm not really familiar with phrases that are more informal (even regarded as slang) in English, I wanted to know what exactly does this phrase mean and when would it be appropriate to use this?

Comment: It might be helpful if you [edit] your post and provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), like the entire comment or the surrounding context.

Comment: Actually, the entire comment was this phrase alone. And well... I forgot what the post was about.

Comment: I've usually heard it as a question in Black American dialect: "You feel me?" meaning "Do you understand what I'm telling you?"

Comment: I'm certain that "you feel me" is an entirely different phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying "You'll feel me on this." is like saying "You know EXACTLY what I mean." At a core level deeper than thinking the same, you'll FEEL the same.

It's more of an emotional language and used for bonding. We as humans are emotional creatures, so when someone say's "you'll feel me on this" it builds a deeper connection between the people talking.

In short, this is a good phrase to use to make someone feel connected to you on a deeper level, deeper than them just understanding the literal words you're saying.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful! So, just for clarification, is it like an informal way of saying that I empathize with someone?

Answer (score 0):

"You'll feel me on this" means You'll agree with me on this or you’ll know exactly what I mean.

Comment: Can you expand on this ao give more details? Is this a common phrase in some dialect or is it universal across the English-speaking world?