# What does "Do you feel me?" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

See this conversation,

> Dad: You need to make your bed.
>
> Son: I don't know how to make the bed.
>
> Dad: Do you feel me? You need to do like this.

so, What does "**Do you feel me?**" mean?

Comment: That's a strange example, but it means "do you understand me?"

Comment: Well, it can mean "Do you know what I feel?" or "Do you understand me?" I suppose in this context the father may be annoyed and he expresses it as a rhetorical question. At least without non-verbal clues this is my first thought.

Comment: Also: http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You%20feel%20me%3F.

Comment: I don't know where you found this conversation, but "You need to do like this" is not idiomatic English.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/116186/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Dad: Do you feel me? You need to do like this.

The dad is speaking poor english here, but he wants his son to make the bed, and then I assume that the dad shows his son how to make the bed.

"Do you feel me?" is an informal phrase and it means "do you understand what I am saying?" However, I would expect "do you feel me?" at the end of someone speaking, not at the beginning.